# How to get a list of users of bugzilla project using XMLRPC after login

Tags: php, curl, keyword, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm looking for XMLRPC keywords to find out a list of users of a BUGZILLA project.

Here is my code, login works fine and im' able to use several keywords to find out what i need : Bug.search, Bug.fields.

```
public function loginBz($url,$login,$password,$getResult)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $URI = $url;
    $xml_data = array(
    'login' => $login,
    'password' => $password,
    'remember' => 1
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    $file_cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $options = array(
    //CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_URL     => $URI,
    CURLOPT_POST    => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( 'Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8' )
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("User.login", $xml_data);
    //  var_dump($request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch); // Array( [id] => 1 ) for example

    $response = xmlrpc_decode($server_output);

    //print_r ($response);
    if($getResult)
        return $response;
    else 
        return $ch;
}

public function getFieldsBz($product,$component,$ch){
    $xml_data = array(
    'product'     => $product,
    'component' => '$component'
    );

    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("Bug.user", $xml_data); // create a request for filing bugs
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch); // Array( [id] => 1 ) for example
    $response = xmlrpc_decode($server_output);

    return $response;       
}
```

I've been searching into **[BugZilla API](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)** but did not found what I need : List of Users for a product Bz. 
Does anyone know which keyword I have to use in ***xmlrpc_encode_request(keyword,array_filter)*** ?

It would help :)

Answer (score 0):

First there isn't a method called Bug.user, see https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html for a complete list.
There is a method called User.get, see https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/User.html#get
There is a parameter called groups which may do what you want depending on how you setup Bugzilla security.
You can use https://xmlrpc.devzing.com/ to experiment or if you upgrade to Bugzilla 5.x you can use the new REST API. https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/5.0/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/REST.html